# Split given timestamp into year month day period format

Tags: r

I am writing a R code and I have a problem to split Date format into year, month, day, hour format. 
I have dataframe named Metadata has a column `X_date`, contains timestamp like `'01.01.2020 00:00:00', '01.01.2020 01:00:00'` and so on.
I want to change this `x_date` column into additional four columns namely `year`, `month`, `day` and `hour`. I tried this way using some previous answer:
`Metadata$Date <- as.Date(Metadata$X_date)`

`Metadata$Time <- format(as.POSIXct(Metadata$X_date) ,format = "%Y:%m:%d %H")`

It gave me this error:
`Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

I am very new to R programming. Please help me. Thnak you for your time.

Comment: The `format` should be `"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"` assuming that day is the first, then month and year. as the quesiton is to split it. `library(dplyr);library(lubridate); Metadata %>% mutate(X_date = dmy_hms(Date), year = year(Date), month = month(Date), day = day(Date), hour = hour(Date))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `format` specified should match the order in which all the components of 'Date/Time' occurs in the original vector.  Assuming that 'day' is first, followed by 'month', the coversion in 'POSIXct' would be

```
as.POSIXct(Metadata$X_date, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

---

As we want to create new columns, this can be done with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
Metadata %>%
    mutate(X_date = dmy_hms(X_date), 
            year = year(X_date), 
            month = month(X_date),
            day = day(X_date), 
            hour = hour(X_date))
```

Comment: I got this  `Error in mutate(., X_date = dmy_hms(X_date), year = year(X_date), month = month(X_date),  : 
  could not find function "mutate"`. No clue why

Comment: @rjt  Have you loaded `library(tidyverse)` or `library(dplyr)`

Comment: yes, `library(dplyr)
library(gdata)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)`

Comment: @rjt  Try it on a fresh session and then load only `library(dplyr);library(lubridate);library(ggplot2)` May be there is a conflict between your `tidyverse` package dplyr version and `dplyr` version

Comment: thanks a lot, seems it's working but small doubt. It shows me expected results in console but how can I save this result to `Metadata` dataframe? After the code you suggested I just tried Metadata <- Metadata but didn't wok.

Comment: @rjt  Sorry you need to update by `Metadata <- Metadata %>%...`

Comment: Sorry, I tried both way but `Metadata <- Metadata %>%` makes Metadata dataframe empty and `Metadata <- Metadata` doesn't make any difference.`Metadata %>%
  mutate(X_date = dmy_hms(X_date), 
         year = year(X_date), 
         month = month(X_date),
         day = day(X_date), 
         hour = hour(X_date))
Metadata <- Metadata %>%` This is how I am trying.

Comment: @rjt I meant `Metadata <- Metadata %>%
    mutate(X_date = dmy_hms(X_date), 
            year = year(X_date), 
            month = month(X_date),
            day = day(X_date), 
            hour = hour(X_date))`

Comment: Works absolute fine! Thank you very much.